# g77 running problem

Tags: software-installation

I installed g77 following the procedure given to an earlier question. 
But when I run it following errors comes up, could you please help someone to get this thing solved.

```
drjinasena@drjinasena-All-Series:~/minimum$ g77 sorting.f

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These two issues are described in more detail [here](http://seanelvidge.com/2017/01/install-g77-on-ubuntu-14-04/). But the overview solution is:

The "cannot find crt1.o...." error is a bug which has been talked about [before](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/+bug/738098). The get around is to find where crti.o lives on your system:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name "crti.o"

/usr/lib32/crti.o
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/libx32/crti.o
```

Take the location with "linux-gnu" in and add it to the environmental variable LIBRARY_PATH. To do this edit your .bashrc file and then reload it. Namely:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Then add to the end:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH
```

(replacing the path with the correct one for your system). Save and exit the file and then reload it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The "cannot find -lgcc_s" means ld can't find a library (libgcc_s). You can help it, by finding the library yourself:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name libgcc_s.so
```

which returned a couple of versions for me, so I picked the latest one (which was located here: '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so') and then checked where ld was expecting the library:

```
ld -lgcc_s --verbose
```

This returned loads of text, but the main bit we are interested in is right at the end:

```
==================================================
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libgcc_s.a failed
ld: cannot find -lgcc_s[/text]
```

If we make a symbolic link from where the actual file is to one of these locations then we'll be all done:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```